# Flex Mobile 4.6, How to pass data (selectedItem) from master to detail view in splitview

Tags: apache-flex

I have a tabbed view with in the second tab a splitview controller.

The master view shows a list. When selecting an item from that list it opens a second view with a new list by using navigator.pushView.

When I select an item in the second view/list it has to be passed to the detailview. Is there a simple solution available?

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing your display hierarchy. Can you post code or a screenshot"?  Which piece is the detailview?  And I assume you mean Flex Mobile 4.5 not Flex Mobile 6.5?

Comment: Off course i meant 4.6...

I have a splitview, leftpane, rightpane. The left pane contains a list (populated by PHP webservice). I click an item in the list. The result should be that the results have to be shown in the rightpane (also as a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pushView()` method has the following syntax:

```
pushView(viewClass:Class, 
    data:Object = null, 
    context:Object = null, 
    transition:spark.transitions:ViewTransitionBase = null):void
```

> **data** specifies any data passed to the view. This object is written to
>   the View.data property of the new view

Taken from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html#WSe11993ea1bd776e54e19b82b12a43a4fb49-8000

If is not clear enough let me know :)

Also you can check this example http://bbishop.org/flex/flexmobileexamples/FlexMobileOnWeb.html - view source enabled